# How to store elements of a list into independent vectors

Tags: r, list, vector, transformation

I want to transform the elements of a list into independent vectors that are saved in and usably from the global environment.

Imagine a list "the.list" that consists of three elements.

```
$a
[1] 1 2 3
$b
[1] 6 7 8
$c
[1] 11 12 13
```

Is there a way of storing each of the elements as individual vectors?

I have tried to use 
`lapply (the.list, as.vector)`
, but the result is the same as simply printing the list.
 Also, using 
`unlist (the.list)`
returns a simple vector of 
`1:15`, in which the distinct sets 
(`1:3, 6:8, 11:13`) 
are non distinguishable.

I am looking for a function/way to transform the elements of the list into what would would manually be

```
a<-c(1:3)
b<-c(6:8)
c<-c(11:13)
```

Many thanks.

Comment: You can use `assign` but what is the problem in keeping them in a `list` ?

Comment: Are you looking for `list2env(your_list, globalenv())`?

Comment: "assign" does the job! Thanks. I need the elements for further subsetting of another character vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Creating some data
my_list <- list(a = c(1:3), b = c(4:5), c = c(6:10))

# Assigning each vector to element name    
for (i in 1:length(my_list)) {
  assign(names(my_list[i]), as.vector(my_list[i]))
}
```